# Check if class property value exists in list of objects

Tags: python, class, attributes, any

I have a class with 2 properties:

```
class ButtonPress():
    def __init__(self, time, button):
        self.time = time
        self.button = button
```

I create a list with `ButtonPress` objects inside them:

```
buttonlist = []
buttonlist.append(ButtonPress("25", "a")
buttonlist.append(ButtonPress("5", "b"))
```

How can I check if within the list any of the objects has a specific `time` value? I'm trying:

```
if "25" in buttonlist[:]['time']
    print("yaaay")
else:
    print("feck")
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Start with a simpler question: how would you check if some *single* `ButtonPress` object `b` has a time of `"25"`?

Comment: Do you have many ButtonPress events? Can such an event happen twice in one time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
class ButtonPress():
    def __init__(self, time, button):
        self.time = time
        self.button = button

buttonlist = []
buttonlist.append(ButtonPress("25", "a"))
buttonlist.append(ButtonPress("5", "b"))

if any(button.time == "25" for button in buttonlist):
    print("yaaay")
else:
    print("feck")
```

**Output**

```
yaaay
```

An alternative using `in` is the following:

```
if "25" in (button.time for button in buttonlist):
```